# Ocultar .php en mi servidor

Tags: php, apache, server

tengo un sistema en php en un servidor Ubuntu con Apache 2.4.29 (algo viejo), y quisiera saber como ocultar las extensiones php de mi sistema ya que desde el htaccess  no me esta funcionando, esto es lo que intente en base a lo que busque en google:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Cabe aclarar que en mi pc en local host ese codigo funciona, pero al pasarlo al servidor no, gracias.

Comment: Hola, Marcos. ¿Cómo tienes la configuración de apache? Quizá interfiera con lo que hay en el .htaccess por prioridad.

Comment: Hola, te refieres a mi configuración en el php.ini?

Comment: Aqui esta la documentación oficial de PHP espero te sirva https://www.php.net/manual/es/security.hiding.php